# Angular 7 /JS , video.currentTime doesn't work properly on Google Chrome but work properly with Firefox

Tags: angular, google-chrome, video

I've added a custom video player on my angular app, everything works fine on firefox but when i try to set currentTime for my video it return a 0 output.

A littkle code for explaining what i'm saying:

```
this.bar.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {

  const scrubTime = (evt.offsetX / this.bar.offsetWidth) * this.mediaVideoPlaying.duration;

  this.mediaVideoPlaying.currentTime = scrubTime;

});
```

On firefox it's working well but when i debug on chrome currentTime automatically return 0.
I'm working on local environment on i've tested on chrome version: Version 77.0.3865.90 .

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will reply to my post, the problem can come from the server side.
Be sure your server provide (in the header of the request) the right "content-type" so for exemple "video/mp4", for an mp4 video, the "Access-Ranges" to "bytes" and "Connection to "keep-alive".

Chrome is a base of Chromium who work differently as Firefox, it call the server everytime you update the currentTime of the video or audio files.

I got this issue after coding my own web server from scratch.
It work well with an apache server (if it's well configured of course).